# Ho to get only columns that have value in a specefic line higher than value in other lines in R

Tags: r, dataframe, row, multiple-columns, data-manipulation

I have data like this

```
    C1 C2 c3 c4 c5 c6 c7 c8
A   5  7  10  1  3  2 14  2
B   3  7  12  2  10 5  8  3
C   2  5  10  2  5  5  8  10
D  10  4  18  5  7  4 18  9
```

I want only the columns that have value in line D higher than values in all other columns

So the result is

```
    C1   c3 c4  c6 c7 
A   5    10  1   2 14 
B   3    12  2   5  8 
C   2    10  2   5  8  
D  10    18  5   4 18
```

I also want to know how to specify comparaison with only some lines for example if i want the columns that have value in line D higher than values in line A and C
so the result is

```
    C1   c3 c4 C5  c6 c7 
A   5    10  1  3  2  14 
B   3    12  2 10  5   8 
C   2    10  2  5  5   8  
D  10    18  5  7  4  18
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

We can make a custom that takes arguments the data frame and the columns you want to compare, i.e.

```
f1 <- function(df, row_to_compare, rows){
  d1 <- df[rownames(df) %in% rows,]
  d2 <- df[rownames(df) == row_to_compare,]
  i1 <- colSums(mapply(`>`, d2, d1)) == nrow(d1)
  return(df[i1])
}

f1(df, 'D', c('A', 'C'))

#  C1 c3 c4 c5 c7
#A  5 10  1  3 14
#B  3 12  2 10  8
#C  2 10  2  5  8
#D 10 18  5  7 18
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, can you tell me please, why we used colSums and how it works in this case ? because i know that colSums calculate the sum of rows of each column ? if you can please give me further explication about this line colSums(mapply(`>`, d2, d1)) == nrow(d1) ? also i want please to know how df[i1] return the variable that have true value, thank you very much